# Can you defer statusCode in jquery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

I see that they added a function for status codes

> statusCode(added 1.5)Map Default: {} A
>   map of numeric HTTP codes and
>   functions to be called when the
>   response has the corresponding code.
>   For example, the following will alert
>   when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({   statusCode: {404: function() {
    alert('page not found');   } });
```

> If the request is successful, the
>   status code functions take the same
>   parameters as the success callback; if
>   it results in an error, they take the
>   same parameters as the error

I am wondering can you do something like `$.ajax({...}).statusCode(function(){...});`

Simliar to how you can do

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The function is, as far as I can tell, undocumented, but the functionality seems to be exactly as you'd expect -- you pass in an object map of handler functions where the key is the HTTP response code and the value is the handler function.  [See the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L583).

**Example**

```
$.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .statusCode({
        200: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        404: function(){
            alert('not found');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I guess if your using .success though that is like a 200 response right?

Comment: @chobo2 `success` will run on status codes <400. Otherwise, `error` handlers would run. `statusCode` allows more granularity, if you need it.

Comment: jQuery 1.5 doesn't fire the 400, 401 as given for JSONP:

        401: function(){
            alert('not authorized');
        },
        400: function(){
            alert('bad request');
        }

Due to the known issue, seems like.

Comment: @Mohammed It's impossible to do that. JSONP works by inserting a `script` element into the page: there is no programmatic notification of failures of `script` elements.